# The role of RDFS axioms and entailment rules in semantic modelling

Tags: semantic-web, rdfs

I have some trouble in understanding the differences between axioms and entailment rules in RDFS.

Are axioms basically the structure of the model and the entailment rules the values added to it?

Comment: When you say "RDFS axioms", are you referring to "axiomatic triples", as defined by RDF Semantics?

Answer (score 0):

An axiom is simply a statement of fact assumed to be true in your knowledge base. An entailment rule is an axiom but allows entailments to be derived from that rule.